# Post a JSON object on conditional input -- Django Restframework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Iam working on Django Restframework. I want to POST into an API to create an object.

The problem is the condition I want to make, is itself in the POST data.

For example, I have 5 fields:

1. Name
2. Lastname
3. Email
4. is_member
5. membership_id

I want to create a membership_id, if the user sends "is_member== True" while data posts.

**Problem:** The data does get posted but the "membership_id" is blank. And no errors received.
I could conclude that the reason is the "if/else" condition is triggered before all the fields are set.

I tried to give the "if/else" condition

1. when the function starts
2. Inside the object which save the entry ie `user_object`.

But nothing works

Iam until here

```
def create_user(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
        lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        is_member = request.POST.get('is_member')   # default is = False
        category = request.POST.get('category')
        timestamp = int(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp()*1000)
        if is_member == True:
            membership_id = hashString(str(timestamp))
        else:
            membership_id = ""
    try:

        user_object = MasterUser(
            firstname = firstname,
            lastname = lastname,
            email = email,
            is_member = is_member,
            membership_id = membership_id
        )
        user_object.save()
        
        return HttpResponse('User successfully created')
```

Is it possible or do I have to look out for some different apporach.
Any ideas are welcomed! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have understood from your question is you want to store membership id as some value if it's true and if it's false then store as blank.

I have two suggestions for you:
1.Try if statement like the following:

```
if is_member == 'True':
   membership_id = hashString(str(timestamp))
else:
   membership_id = ""
```

2.Try and print 'is_member' and 'membership_id' in the console within the if statement and check what's getting stored in there. I guess your 'hashString' method is not working.

```
print(is_member)
if is_member == True:
       membership_id = hashString(str(timestamp))
       print(membership_id )
else:
       membership_id = ""
```

Everything else must not change. If you still can't find the solution, then you must cross check your 'model' and the 'MasterUser' method.

Also the try method should go inside the if statement not outside. Like this:

```
def create_user(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
        lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        is_member = request.POST.get('is_member')   # default is = False
        category = request.POST.get('category')
        timestamp = int(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp()*1000)
        if is_member == True:
            membership_id = hashString(str(timestamp))
        else:
            membership_id = ""
        try:

            user_object = MasterUser(
                firstname = firstname,
                lastname = lastname,
                email = email,
                is_member = is_member,
                membership_id = membership_id
            )
            user_object.save()
        
            return HttpResponse('User successfully created')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('User not created')
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks Rohit. I was actually trying to pass boolean value without string ie True/False rather than "True"/"False" and also Try/Except method was outside the If statement.

Appreciate the help! Thanks a lot